# Swift | DynamicTableView - Trigger Action with ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a DynamicTableView and every Cell has an ImageView. How do I make an Action with knowing the indexPath.row?

The only way I know is to make a TapGestureRecognizer – that works but I then don't know which row I clicked.

So I need something like DidSelectRowAt from the TableView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

This Action should only happen when I press the ImageView not the whole Row, therefore I can't use DidSelectRowAt from the TableView.

Thats what I did right now:

```
class DownloadsViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DownloadsViewController.tappedMe))

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadsViewCell

        cell.fileInfo.image = UIImage(named: "detail1")
        cell.fileInfo.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        cell.fileInfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

func tappedMe(){
    print(arrayDocuments(IndexPath.row))
}
}
```

My whole DownloadViewContoller Class Code [is here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59cbee58ca424945eb22e72d)

My DownloadViewCell Screenshot [is here](https://imgur.com/a/1hiBV)

Does anyone have an Idea?

Thank you!

Comment: it would be great if you provide more code.

Comment: @SourLeangChhean I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the ImageView like you had before, and then just add a blank Button over it and use the method from the Answer from Ilya V. with the IBAction

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a property to your cell: `var indexPath: IndexPath`.
2. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` do `cell.indexPath = indexPath`
3. In your cell subclass add `tapGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView` which triggers method in cell subclass.
4. Make a delegate protocol for your cell:

   ```
   protocol YourCellDelegate: class {

      func imagePressed(indexPath: IndexPath)

   }
   ```
5. Make your ViewController adopt this protocol.
6. In your cell subclass add property `weak var delegate: YourCellDelegate?`
7. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` do `cell.delegate = self`
8. In cell tapRecognizer selector call delegate method `delegate?.imagePressed(indexPath: indexPath)`
9. In your viewController you'll receive `imagePressed` method call with indexPath as an argument.

Comment: What do you mean with cell Subclass. I have my normal Class "DownloadsViewController" then my SubClass just for the Cell "DownloadsViewCell" where I only connected the Outlets UIImageView and Label?

Comment: @ChrisBerger DownloadsViewCell is your UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: Doesn't let me set the Image for UIImageview in the DownloadsViewCell, I guess you can only set it in the TableViewController: https://imgur.com/a/1hiBV  ||  And where exactly and how do I make a delegate Protocol?

Comment: So all I did right now is add "cell.indexPath = indexPath" and "cell.delegate = self" to the cellForRowAtPath in the ViewController and my DownloadsViewCell looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/Sfh56 ||  Please Help

Comment: @ChrisBerger For selector you need to create your own method in DownloadsViewCell where you call delegate method

Comment: I already did but it doesn't know the indexPath! That was the Problem!, not passing Data. Please look at the code I updated in the question

Comment: And I CANT set the image and taprecognizer in DownloadViewCell! Only in CellForRowAtPath https://imgur.com/a/Sfh56

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get cell by

```
recognizer.view
```

on tap gesture method and

```
func indexPath(for cell: UITableViewCell) -> IndexPath?
```

returns an index path representing the row and section of a given table-view cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses a custom `UIImageView` subclass.

- Create a subclass of `UIImageView` - `MyImageView` (or something else more appropriate)
- Create a delegate for the subclass - `MyImageViewDelegate`
- Add a delegate method called `myImageViewTapped(imageView: MyImageView)`
- Override the `touchesEnded` method to call the delegate method
- Add a property in `MyImageView` called `indexPath` that stores the index path of the cell that this image view is in.
- In your table cells, use `MyImageView` instead of a regular `UIImageView`.
- Set the delegate of the `MyImageView` to `self` i.e the VC.
- Set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the image view's `indexPath` to the `indexPath` parameter
- Now implement the delegate method and in the method, you will know which image view is tapped by accessing `indexPath`!

Comment: bad idea to add indexPath property to imageView

Answer (score 0):

You can use property "tag" imageView to save indexPath.row and use it later in the selector

```
class DownloadsViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadsViewCell

    cell.fileInfo.image = UIImage(named: "detail1")
    cell.fileInfo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tappedMe(_ :)))
    cell.fileInfo.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func tappedMe(_ sender: AnyObject){
    print("Tap to imageView in cell No. - \(sender.view.tag)")
}
}
```